# Creating block objects by assigning values to many2many field

Tags: python, odoo, many-to-many, odoo-8, openerp-8

I'm trying to create a feature to create massive instances through a wizard, assigning values ​​to some many2many fields, but at the time of the test I get an error:

```
Singleton expected: model3(167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 188, 187, 188, 190, 191, 193, 194, 195, 1978, 1978, 2007, 1920, 202, 203, 204, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246)
```

I leave the code in case you can help me.

```
class Modelo1Model(models.Model):
    _name = 'modelo1'

    mod1_modelo3_ids = fields.Many2many('modelo3')

class Modelo2Model(models.Model):
    _name = 'modelo2'

    mod2_modelo3_ids = fields.Many2many('modelo3')

class Modelo3Model(models.Model):
    _name = 'modelo3'

    #...

class Modelo1Wizard(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'modelo1.wizard'

    def _default_i(self):
        return self.env['modelo1'].browse(self._context.get('active_ids'))

    modelo1_ids = fields.Many2many(
        'modelo1',
        default = _default_i)

    @api.multi
    def create_modelo2(self):
        for i in self.modelo1_ids:
            registros_many2many = i.mod2_modelo3_ids.ids
            i.ensure_one()
            modelo2_obj = self.env['modelo2']
            modelo2_vals = {
                'mod2_modelo3_ids': registros_many2many
                 }
            modelo2_create_id = modelo2_obj.create(modelo2_vals)
```

Comment: Can you post the full error message?

Comment: result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/server/addons_custom/addons/prueba12_wizard/wizard/modelo1_wizard.py", line 70, in create_modelo2
    'mod1_modelo3_ids,
  File "/opt/odoo/server/openerp/fields.py", line 825, in __get__
    record.ensure_one()
  File "/opt/odoo/server/openerp/models.py", line 5323, in ensure_one
    raise except_orm("ValueError", "Expected singleton: %s" % self)
except_orm: ('ValueError', 'Expected singleton: modelo3(250, 252)')

Answer (score 0):

`@api.multi`

When you decorate your method with this decorator you imply that `self` will be a recordset. In order to properly write to your records you have to iterate. Example:

```
@api.multi
    def create_modelo2(self):
        for record in self:
            for i in record.modelo1_ids:
```

Comment: I've tried what you tell me and the error keeps popping up. I think the problem is trying to get the values from the many2many field:                                             modelo2_vals = {'mod2_modelo3_ids': registros_many2many}

Answer (score 0):

Solved by following [**this**](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F31853402%2Ffilling-many2many-field-odoo-8&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNHqE4b00z7MOltg8KOGaVyd7viL0Q), here show how to work with fields x2many